# android variable font fontVariationSettings

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

Using API 29 and a variable font (Inter v3.19 from google fonts, .ttf)

It seems no matter what value I set for `fontVariationSettings` the TextView would just ignore the setting. When put inside a styles.xml values like `'wght' 700` would trigger a build error with  `Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.`

How should one be using a variable font on Android?

Comment: What's the font you're using? (Is it, in fact, a variable font?)

Comment: it is a variable font. what's strange is it seems to work when set in code using `FontBuilder` but using the layout xml it doesnt

Answer (score -1):

You can [setFontVariationSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/fonts/Font.Builder#setFontVariationSettings(java.lang.String)) before [build()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/fonts/Font.Builder#build()).

```kotlin
// ...
builder.setFontVariationSettings("'wght' 700")
builder.build()
```

Or try the [Typeface.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.Builder). It works great for me.

```kotlin
val builder = Typeface.Builder(/* ... */)
builder.setFontVariationSettings("'wght' 700")
textView.typeface = builder.build()
```

Comment: The question was really why setting it in xml (layout.xml, styles.xml, ...) does not work